# Angular+ngrx: how to keep store state on router url traversing?

Tags: angular, rxjs, store, ngrx

I know that the store resets every time the page is refreshed by user (so called "hard refresh"), but I hoped that it stays intact when a user traverses pages using angular router. But, as I see, it resets anyway.

Am I wrong? is there any way to keep store without saving in to LocalStorage or using other hacks?

app.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

    // Routing
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

    // Ngrx
    import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
    import {
      StoreRouterConnectingModule,
      RouterStateSerializer,
    } from '@ngrx/router-store';
    import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
    import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';

    // Other
    import { reducers, metaReducers } from './core/reducers';
    import { CustomRouterStateSerializer } from './core/utils/router.utils';
    import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';

    // Environment
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

    // Components
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { NotFoundComponent } from './core/components/not-found.component';
    import { NotAuthorizedComponent } from './core/components/not-authorized.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './core/components/home.component';
    import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
    import { EventsModule } from "./events/events.module";

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NotFoundComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        NotAuthorizedComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MaterialModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }), 
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({stateKey: 'router'}),
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        UsersModule,
        EventsModule

  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomRouterStateSerializer },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

./core/reducers/index.ts

```
import {
  ActionReducerMap,
  ActionReducer,
  MetaReducer, createFeatureSelector, createSelector,
} from '@ngrx/store';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { RouterStateUrl } from '../utils/router.utils';
import * as fromRouter from '@ngrx/router-store';
import * as fromAuth from '../../users/reducers/auth.reducer';

import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';

export interface State {
  router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>,
  auth: fromAuth.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  router: fromRouter.routerReducer,
  auth: fromAuth.reducer
};

export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): ActionReducer<State> {
  return function(state: State, action: any): State {
    console.log('state', state);
    console.log('action', action);

    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production
  ? [logger, storeFreeze]
  : [];

// AUTH reducers
export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<fromAuth.State>('auth');

export const getUser = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  fromAuth.getUser
);
export const getLoaded = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  fromAuth.getLoaded
);
export const getError = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  fromAuth.getError
);
```

The idea is to get User credentials from server via HTTP GET, put them in store and then get them from store instead of server. So I have a guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private store: Store<State>, protected router: Router) {
  }

  protected getFromStoreOrAPI(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store
      .select(getUser)
      .do(user => {
        if (!user) this.store.dispatch(new Signin());
      })
      .filter(user => user)
      .take(1);
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getFromStoreOrAPI()
      .switchMap(() => Observable.of(true))
      .catch(() =>  Observable.of(false));
  }
}
```

on `this.store.dispatch(new Signin());` it makes s HTTP call and places data into store.

Problem is, that it makes HTTP calls each time user goes to new page.

Comment: If you reference the store only from a component added by the router or a service provided by such a component it will be recreated when you navigate around. If you hold the store in a service provided in AppModule, it won't lose its state.

Comment: And if I use stores in different modules and combine them by `    StoreModule.forFeature('storeName', reducers)`?

Comment: Why do you think this would be different? If it doesn't work, please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: What state is lost when you navigate to a different route?

Comment: auth part of store.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164468/discussion-between-alexnasonov-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: You've definitely messed up somewhere as the Store isn't lost when navigating to a different route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So stupid of me! Used `<a href="/link">Link</a>` instead of `<a routerLink="/link">Link</a>`!

Answer (score 1):

Check your reducers, I'm sure you've made the mistake of forgetting to return the state in your switch statement:

```
switch(action.type){
       ...
        default:
            return state;
}
```

Comment: No, state is returned